# css matching selector with adjacent class restriction

Tags: css, css-selectors

When I want to match a particular class `my-class-b` that also has another class `my-other-class-a` on the same element I can do

```
.my-class-b.my-other-class-a {
}
```

Also when I want to match by partial class name I can use

```
[class^="my-class-"] {
}
```

Now I want to mix both but it doesn't seem to work. How can I do

```
[class^="my-class-"].my-other-class-a {
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This happens because the class attribute is tested for beginning with the specified class in the css selector `[class^="abc"]`.

If the selector is

```
[class^="my-"]
```

Then

```
class="my-class red"
```

is not the same as

```
class="red my-class"
```

Check it out at http://jsfiddle.net/u5sfge94/

One way around this is to specify a new class that acts as [class^="abc"]. It may make your stylesheet a bit more organized, your code more legible and css rendering a tad faster.

Answer (score 5):

Explanation of @juank in a previous answer is correct: the order you write your classes matter, because ^ stands for beginning of value.

But there are many other attribute selectors using *regexp* notation: `^=`, `*=` and `$=` in particular; resp. for begins with, anywhere and ends with matching.
If you want your selector to match classes containing `my-class` wherever it may be, you should use `*=` (see **Snippet 1**).
But then it'll also match any class not beginning by `my-class` but still containing it.  To avoid this, you can match as you previously did with `^=` and also match `[class*=" my-class"]` (with a space): it'll take into account the case where it isn't the first class written in the value of the class attribute (see **Snippet 2**).

**Resource:** [CSS3 Substring Matching Attribute Selectors](http://www.css3.info/preview/attribute-selectors/) at CSS3.info (link to *REC CSS level 3 Selectors* at the very end)

**Snippet 1:**

```css
[class*='my-class'].my-other-class-a {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-class-a my-other-class-a">Should match 1</div>
<div class="my-class-b my-other-class-a">Should match 2</div>
<div class="my-other-class-a">Nope</div>
<div class="my-other-class-a my-class-a">Should match 3</div>
<div class="my-other-class-a my-class-b">Should match 4</div>
<div class="whatever my-other-class-a my-class-a">Should match 5</div>
<div class="other my-other-class-a my-class-b">Should match 6</div>
<div class="my-other-class-a maybe-maybe-not-my-class-a">Beware</div>
```

**Snippet 2:**

```css
[class^='my-class'].my-other-class-a,
[class*=' my-class'].my-other-class-a {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-class-a my-other-class-a">Should match 1</div>
<div class="my-class-b my-other-class-a">Should match 2</div>
<div class="my-other-class-a">Nope</div>
<div class="my-other-class-a my-class-a">Should match 3</div>
<div class="my-other-class-a my-class-b">Should match 4</div>
<div class="whatever my-other-class-a my-class-a">Should match 5</div>
<div class="other my-other-class-a my-class-b">Should match 6</div>
<div class="my-other-class-a maybe-maybe-not-my-class-a">Beware</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly bullet proof, but as long as your "variable" class is the first one, this can work:

```css
div[class^='my-class'][class~='my-other-class-a'] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-class-a my-other-class-a">Hello</div>
<div class="my-class-b my-other-class-a">World</div>
<div class="my-other-class-a">Bye</div>
```